# border between search text and search button in a search box

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/8u8PN/)

html

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" value="search..." />
    <input type="image" value="Q" />
</div>
```

css

```css
.search{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.search input:first-child{
    width: 300px;
}
.search input:nth-child(2){
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.search:after{
    content: " ";
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I couldn't insert `:after` elements in input tag because it won't work as this doesn't have closing tag. So I managed this in main div that is `.search`. The border is showing exactly but I want like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can get the desired result just with CSS.
Give your `:after` an `absolute` position and a negative `margin-top` equal to the padding of the parent. Then give it the height of the parent :

```
.search:after{
    content: " ";
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 66px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

**[The demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u8PN/2/)**

Comment: I was also trying with absolute but was hidden, I knew here the height is must. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the styles

```
border-top: 20px solid #FF0000;
border-bottom: 20px solid #FF0000;
```

to **.search:after**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8u8PN/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least one additional div. Like this :

```
<div class="search">
    <div class="search-text">
        <input type="text" value="search..." />
    </div>
    <div class="search-image">
        <input type="image" value="Q" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You can now apply the border to the `search-text` div.

Comment: but .search have padding value 20px. if you apply border to .search-text then it even look as my need.

Comment: If you change your html structure, you obviously need to change your CSS too.